# Number formation and bridged graphs, connection or coincidence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

**Bridged graphs sequence**

$g(n) =$ "Number of simple connected bridged graphs on $n+2$ nodes".

We have $g(n)=1, 3, 10, 52, 351, 3714,\dots$ from [*A052446*](https://oeis.org/A052446).

**Number formation sequence**

We also have $f(n) =$ "Largest $N$ such that all numbers $1,\dots, N$ can be made using basic operations $+,-,\times,\div$ and parentheses $(\space)$, given optimal set of $n$ digits (to be defined for each $n$) such that all digits are used exactly once."

The conjectured solutions are: $f(n)=1, 3, 10, 52, 351$ so far for $n=1,\dots,5$.

The first three values are true and not hard to prove. The second two values are given by:

$f(4)\ge 52$ since (optimal?) digits $d=\{2,3,4,22\}$ can make numbers $1,\dots,52$.

$f(5)\ge 351$ since (optimal?) digits $d=\{3,6,8,12,37\}$ can make numbers $1,\dots,351$, which can be [seen by clicking here](https://pastebin.com/0AAVXCKc). Note that solutions per $N_0\in[1,N]$ are not necessarily unique.

I conjecture these two are equalities based on computations. That is, I couldn't find a better digit set that would make larger $N$ possible in either case.

**Question**

Notice that so far I have a conjecture pattern:

$$f(n)=g(n)$$

> Is this a coincidence or is there a connection between these two problems?
>
> That is, can we provide arguments for either case?

I don't see a clear connection and would think this is just a coincidence. Can we  prove this is just a coincidence? That is, find $n$ and $d$ such that $f(n)\gt g(n)$? Or prove for some $n$ that for every $d$ we have $f(n)\lt g(n)$?

Or is this not a coincidence? Can we provide arguments why could these two problems be connected? It would be amazing if we could translate number formation to graphs and find optimal $d$ for some $n$ with graph theory.

Can we perhaps find $d$ such that $f(6)=3714$, and continue this pattern? My simple brute force `c++` code is too slow to find significant records for $n\ge 6$. The best I have by sampling random digit cases is $f(6)\ge 2200$, so far.

**Lower bound on $f(n)$**

It can be shown $f(n)\gt 2^n,n\gt 2$, using $d=\{2^0,2^1,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$.

But this is not the best lower bound for this digit set. We have:

$f(n)\ge f_d(n)=1,3,10,26,76,596,2472,\dots$.

Notice this is a weak lower bound and is not sharp. Example: $f(6)\ge2200\gt f_d(6)=596$.

Notice $f(n)=f_d(n)$ for $n\le 3$. Better digit sets might give better bounds for $n\ge 4$.

Comment: What is a bridged graph?

Comment: @lambda "A [bridged graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BridgedGraph.html) is a graph that contains one or more [graph bridges](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphBridge.html)." - A graph  bridge is an edge of a not-necessarily-connected graph $G$ whose removal increases the number of components of $G$ (Harary 1994, p. 26). An edge of a connected graph is a bridge iff it does not lie on any cycle."

Comment: this is almost certainly the Law of Small Numbers operating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidence.

$f(n)$ is not larger than the number of expressions on $n$ numbers. The expressions are in bijection with $n$-leaf rooted binary trees, where its non-leaf vertices are labeled with $\{+,-,×,÷\}$ and its leaves are in bijection with the optimal set of digits. The number of such binary trees is $4^{n-1}\text{Catalan}(n-1)n!$, which is $O(\exp(c n\log n))$ for some constant $c$.

The binary tree $T$ corresponding to a expression $d$ is constructed as follows:

$d$ takes the form $d_1⊕d_2$, where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are expressions, and $⊕$ is a operator. Label the root of $T$ with $⊕$, construct two subtrees $T_1$ and $T_2$ corresponding to $d_1$ and $d_2$, respectively. Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the two children of $T$. [This is a bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Combinatorics).

The (labeled) binary tree can be determined by the following information:

- The structure of the binary tree ($\text{Catalan}(n-1)$ types)
- The labels ($4$ choices for each non-leaf node)
- The leaves ($n!$ bijections from the optimal digit set)

So the number of trees is $4^{n-1}\text{Catalan}(n-1)n!$.

But the number of bridged graphs on $n$ vertices is at least the number of graphs on $n/2$ vertices: just connect two graphs with an edge. The number of graphs on $n$ vertices is roughly $2^{\frac{n^2}2}$, which is faster than $\exp(c n\log n)$, so the number of bridged graphs eventually dominates $f(n)$.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the bijection, or what you mean by "expressions on $n$ numbers"? Example, $n=3$ should have $\gt108$ expressions? But $4^{3-1}C(3)=80$? [List of 108 expr.](https://pastebin.com/SiS8QPte). What am I (or you) missing? - For comparison, I have $3^{n-1}n!(n-1)!\gt f(n)$ in my program, from $F(n)=6 \binom{n}{2} F(n-1)$. We at each step pick one of six distinct ways $x+y,x-y,y-x,x\cdot y, x/y, y/x$ to do operations on a unordered picked pair $x,y\in d$ leaving us with $n-1$ numbers when including $(x\mathop y)$ expression again.

Comment: Well I forgot that the $n$ digits can be permuted, but the argument is still correct.

Comment: Another minor correction, shouldn't it be $n-1$ in Catalan numbers? I now have "$3^{n-1 }\text{Catalan}(n-1) n!$" (taking into consideration $+,\times$ are commutative), so for general four operators it should be "$4^ {n-1} \text{Catalan}(n-1) n!$"? - But I see now that the argument holds either way due to the growth of (bridged) graphs. Accepted.